# What kind of model field to use for a two dimensional array in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to create a Battleship game. I want to create a model for my battleship board, which is going to be 10 rows and 10 columns, with each spot having a coordinate of [x,y]. I'm not sure which model field to use though. So far, this is the code I have for my Board class:

```
class Board(models.Model):
    ships_left = models.IntegerField()
    available_spots = models.???  #This is to contain [x,y] coordinates of open spots
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to create a `Coordinate` class, and have every possible coordinate pair represented:

```
class Coordinate(models.Model):
    x = models.IntegerField()
    y = models.IntegerField()
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board)
    hit = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ship = models.ForeignKey(Ship, null=True)  # assumes you have Ship objects somewhere
```

You can hit a location as follows (assuming `board` is a `Board` object):

```
x = 2
y = 3
location = board.coordinate_set.filter(x=x, y=y)
if location.ship != None:
    # hit a ship! Do something with location.ship object
# either way, save that it was hit
location.hit = True
location.save()
```

This would not be efficient for a large grid, but in this case there are only 100 coordinates per board, so it will likely be reasonable and intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider representing the board as one or more [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) 2-dimensional arrays. For example, you could use a boolean 2d array to track the coordinates upon which a player has already fired, and an integer array to represent the positions of various ships, by giving each ship type a unique integer value (e.g., 0 for open ocean, 1 for destroyer, 2 for carrier, etc.). This will make it very easy to look up whether an attack was a hit and on what type of ship.

Serialization of the array into the database will require a little bit of work; I'd start by having a look at [this article](http://www.michaelgrosner.com/blog/2011/8/9-django-and-numpy.html); it will show you what model methods to consider overriding. In the comments, there is a recommendation to just use cPickle with [django-picklefield](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-picklefield/), which is the route I'd try first, for simplicity.

Answer (score -1):

If it's a one-to-one relationship, I would simply split the coordinate into 2 fields:

```
class Board(models.Model):
    ships_left = models.IntegerField()
    x = models.IntegerField()
    y = models.IntegerField()
```

Problem solved. I don't see the need of building another model and link it with a foreign key.  Complicates things and incurs one more join, which is real cost.